# Python Subprocess Popen Prepare Python Path under Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I am trying to prepare my pythonpath under Ubuntu via subprocess.Popen call, for another script. The call to Python estimateskeleton.py does work fine. However since it needs the python path to be prepared it doesn't work completely correct, since it can not find some other scripts which need to be imported. The export PYTHONPATH command did work with commands.getoutput. However with commands.getoutput the estimateskeleton script still doesn't work / can't find the other files which should be imported. My try to export PYTHONPATH via subprocess.Popen resulted in Error Number 2:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I couldn't find a proper solution with the search function. So I am hoping that one of the more advanced users of this board can help me

Best Regards

```
import subprocess as sub
import os
import commands

proc = sub.Popen(["export", "PYTHONPATH=\"${PYTHONPATH}:/media/sf_myFolder/Scripts/code/\""],
                  stdout=sub.PIPE,
                  stderr=sub.STDOUT)

print proc.communicate()[0]

proc2 = sub.Popen(["python", "estimateskeleton.py"],
                  stdout=sub.PIPE,
                  stderr=sub.STDOUT)

print proc2.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first `Popen` command would work without `shell=True` because `export` is a shell built-in.

However, that won't fix it, because the second process spawned by `Popen` is unaware of the previous variable set in a dead process.

So instead of running the first useless `Popen`, you could add your path to existing `PYTHONPATH` using `os.putenv()` like this:

```
os.putenv("PYTHONPATH",os.pathsep.join([os.getenv("PYTHONPATH",""),"/media/sf_myFolder/Scripts/code"]))
```

so your next python command is run with the added folder in `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Since we're using `shell=True`, an even easier way could be directly issuing a single command that updates the env var just for the shell started: `PYTHONPATH=$PYHTONPATH:something_else command args`.